# php contact form submit with jquery validation

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I have a basic enough contact form that uses jquery client side validation. I started by doing the form in ajax, but now think it will be better to submit it server side, as I need a success page to add Google Analytics tracking on.
So the ajax form went like this:

```
    if (i == 0) {
    $.ajax({        
        beforeSend: preloader,
        type    : 'POST',
        url     : './ajax/contact-form.php',
        data    : $('#contact_form').serialize(),
        success : function(data) {
            $('#popup_form').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

But now I want to change it to

```
if (i == 0) // then go to success.php, else do not submit the form.
```

The i==0 is obviously the validation error count. So how can I disable the form from submitting if i doesn't = 0?

If it helps, here is my form

```
<form action="success.php" id="contact_form" method="post">
<input id="contact_name" name="contact_name" placeholder="name*" type="text" /><span id="contact_name_validate"></span>
<input id="contact_company" name="contact_company" placeholder="company" type="text" />
<input id="contact_email" name="contact_email" placeholder="email*" type="text" /><span id="contact_email_validate"></span>
<input id="contact_telephone" name="contact_telephone" placeholder="telephone*" type="text" /><span id="contact_telephone_validate"></span>
<div id="contact_message"><textarea name="contact_message" placeholder="Enter your message..."></textarea></div>
<input id="contact_button" type="submit" value="Enquire Now" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Is what you are looking for return false?

```
if (i == 0) {
    return true; // submits the form if this is a button click / form submit event handler
}

return false; // notice this, stops form from submitting.
```

Comment: What about `return i == 0`?

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be something that simple.

Comment: @KevinSchmid any way to return false. `return i == 0 ? true : false;`

Comment: What if I wanted to add a loading sign on click too
       'if (i == 0) {
  return true;
  $('#popup_form').html('<img id="contact_preloader" src="./images/preloader.gif" />');'

It wont acknowledge the preloader, and if I put it before return true, it wont submit the form. So how can I show a preloader on submit?

Comment: Add that preloader image at the start of the button click delegate then reverse that id validated = false

Comment: how do you reverse an id? I am not familiar with that?

Comment: Sorry, by that I mean remove the preloader image if validation fails